# Как можно деструктуризировать обьект состояния чтобы добвить или поменять только определенное значение при помощи хука useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, объекты, react-hook

При классовой компоненте я бы сделал так:

```
    this.state = {
       name: "" 
       text: ""
    }

   this.setState({
      ...state,
      text: "123",
   })
```

Как это сделать с использованием useState ?

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState({ name: "", text: "" })
setData( prev => prev.text = "123")
```

такой записью если и меняет то только 1 параметр.

Comment: setFilterData( prev => {{  ...prev, text: "123 }} ) тоже не работает)

Comment: setFilterData( prev => prev = {
            ...prev,
            [name]: value,
        } )

Comment: решил так, закрыто)

Comment: Лучше сделать две state переменных, раз они независимые и менять каждую тогда, когда нужно.

Comment: а если таких переменных много и некоторые из них обьекты с обьектами ?)

Comment: Нужно смотреть конкретный примерю Как правило объекты не нужны

Answer (score 1):

Если `data` простой объект (без вложенных полей), то можно

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState({ name: "", text: "" })
setData(prev => ({ ...prev, text: "123" }))
```

Но в таком случае у тебя будет целиком меняться объект `data`.
Как вариант ты можешь разбить это на два `useState`.
Если не хочешь разбивать на или быть аккуратным, держа в голове, что после вызова `setData`, объект `data` каждый раз будет новым (новая ссылка).